# Sceneform FBX asset weird UV

Tags: arcore, fbx, sceneform

I am just starting Sceneform for AR Core development. So I've been testing both .obj and .fbx...

For the obj file, the texture gets imported perfectly fine, but the fbx one's UV seems to be off in a weird way...I've tried just flipping the texture/rotating (who knows, might be Zbrush's flipped problem too), but it's not that simple...

My final result is I have to flip the UVs, rotate it by 180 degrees, then move it upwards, but still have some UV island being off.

Wonder if it's some auto center or UV re-layout thing going on with Sceneform.

I do prefer fbx than obj though, since it allows other texture maps like normal, roughness, metalness, ao...etc. Plus, I am still waiting on the fbx animation import option in the future.
[here's what it looks like in Maya, then sceneform asset in obj & fbx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHNDJ.jpg)
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for posting this question.  For issues that are more like bugs versus coding, I'd suggest posting an issue on the GitHub repository for the SDK: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues.

Comment: Got it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with sceneform 1.0.1 and fbx files - UV's are all inverted vertically.  This will be fixed in the next version.